# How to take sum of an empty div with an id?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Write a function named "additionCalculator" that that doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return a value. This function will control the logic for a web-based calculator that adds two numbers. There will be two text boxes on the web page with ids of "input_one" and "input_two" and an empty div with an id of "sum". Read the values of the two text boxes and write the addition of these two values inside the div.

```
function additionCalculator(){
    var one = parseInt(document.getElementById('input_one'));
    var two = parseInt(document.getElementById('input_two'));
    var sum = one + two;
    document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
}
```

I can't seem to add the two numbers together. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementById` returns an HTML element - you want the `value` of the element (I assume these are inputs) - so you need to get the actual property:

```
var one = parseInt(document.getElementById('input_one').value);
var two = parseInt(document.getElementById('input_two').value);
```

When setting the value back to the div - use the `innerHTML` property:

```
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: I am still not getting the sum in the empty div.

Comment: @Anonymous - Try setting the `innerHTML` property of the `div` and not the `value` - div elements do not have a `value` attribute.

Comment: You also can you the + operator to parse string to number. result = +str + +str

Comment: @Anonymous - Pop open your console and see if you're receiving any errors. It may help to recreate this problem in a JSFiddle

Comment: Your code is returning <div id="sum"></div>. It is suppose to return <div id="sum">0</div> where "input_one" value is -87 and "input_two" value is 87.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think what you're missing is a button that calls the action for the calculation to happen. Also remember to change your statements to get the `value` of the `inputs` and to target the `innerHTML` of the empty `div`

```js
document.getElementById('sumBtn').onclick = function additionCalculator(){
    var one = parseInt(document.getElementById('input_one').value);
    var two = parseInt(document.getElementById('input_two').value);
    var sum = one + two;
    document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input_one">
<input type="text" id="input_two">
<button id="sumBtn">Add</button>
<div id="sum"></div>
```